# Grails 2.1.1 with Terracotta and Ehcache integration

Tags: ehcache, terracotta, grails-2.1

I'm trying to integrate Grails 2.1.1 with Terracotta and Ehcache but I'm not getting any good results whatsoever.

Could anybody give me some advice in order to configure it? I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the subj now.
First create `ehcache.xml` in your `grails-app/conf` directory. It should look like that:

```xml
<ehcache>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

 <terracottaConfig url="vm4:9510"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                           

  <defaultCache                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      maxElementsInMemory="50"                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      eternal="false"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      timeToIdleSeconds="20"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      timeToLiveSeconds="20"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      overflowToDisk="false"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      diskPersistent="false"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"                                                                                                                                                                                                          
       />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

   <cache name="processedUrlCache"                                                                                                                                                                                                              
         maxElementsInMemory="50000"                                                                                                                                                                                                           
         eternal="true">                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      <terracotta />                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   </cache>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

</ehcache>
```

Consider that terracottaConfig url should point to your actual host:port where `Terracotta server` lives. Make sure that your tarracotta cache node has `<terracotta/>` subnode (similarly to my processUrlCache entry).

Now, put these 3 jars into your project lib directory:
`ehcache-core-ee-2.6.2.jar`, `ehcache-terracotta-ee-2.6.2.jar`, `terracotta-toolkit-1.6-runtime-ee-5.2.0.jar`

Actual version may differ (but it should be exactly the same as on your `terracotta` server, so my suggestion is to take those jars from server lib directories).

Now, run your server (`start-tc-server.sh` or `start-tc-server.bat` depending on Unix/Windows platform) and run your grails app. For the first start I would suggest you enabling debug logs in your Config.groovy file by putting

```
debug 'net.sf.ehcache'
```

into your `log4j` section.

Let me know would it help you.

Comment: Hey @archer, did you make any more progress / experiences with this? Currently working on such a setup and have to admit that it is hard to find good documentation!

Comment: what kind of documentation you're looking for?

Comment: Hey archer! Thanks for getting back to me. I managed to set up the distributed 2nd level cache incl. session sharing now.
But there is one thing that I find very inconvenient, maybe you have a hint for me: how do you handle working in local environments? I don't really want to setup a terracotta instance on all local machines. How do you do it? Just remove the config?

Comment: I've setup one remote terracota instance and hardcode it location in all ehcache.xml files working in local dev envoronments. That's simple, man ;)

Comment: True, did that in the meantime. Remaining issue is running grails with the "-noreloading" option. That is very inconvenient for development in my case. Any more thoughts?